# I am getting a different font height from DirectWrite font text metric than I requested as the height parameter

Tags: c++, text, height, metric, directwrite

Can anyone explain this?

Code below:

```
// - change font size to specified point(pt) size.
// - returns false if there is an error, or true otherwise.

bool GraphicsDirect2D::TextSetFontSize(int size)
{

if (size <= 0)
{
    assert(0 && "Error: Invalid size parameter.");
    return false;
}

// if size has not changed, return
float currentFontSizeDIP = m_pDWTextFormat->GetFontSize();
float currentFontSizePoints = ConvertDIPToPointSize(currentFontSizeDIP);

if (currentFontSizePoints == size)
    return true;

// otherwise, create new object for new text size
IDWriteTextFormat *pNewTextFormat = NULL;


if (FAILED(m_pDWFactory->CreateTextFormat(
    StringToWString(m_textCurrentSettings.strFont).c_str(),
    NULL,
    DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_REGULAR,
    DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
    DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
    ConvertPointSizeToDIP(size),
    L"en-us",
    &pNewTextFormat)))
{
    assert(0 && "Error.");
    return false;
}



{
    IDWriteTextLayout *m_pDWTextLayout = NULL;
    DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS tm;

    if (FAILED(m_pDWFactory->CreateTextLayout(
        L"Arial",
        0,
        pNewTextFormat,
        100,
        100,
        &m_pDWTextLayout)))
    {
        Destroy();
        assert(0 && "Error.");
        return false;
    }

    if (FAILED(m_pDWTextLayout->GetMetrics(&tm)))
    {
        assert(0 && "Error.");
    }

    m_fontHeight = tm.height;

    m_pDWTextLayout->Release();
}       


// release the old object
if (m_pDWTextFormat)
{
    m_pDWTextFormat->Release();
    m_pDWTextFormat = NULL;
}

// and point to the new one
m_pDWTextFormat = pNewTextFormat;

m_textCurrentSettings.size = size;

return true;
}
```

This function is from a class I'm using to provide a graphics interface for Direct2D (and DirectWrite for text). The function replaces a font it is storing as the 'current' one to one of a new size, and updates a size variable for reference.

The problem is that if I pass in 16 to the function (for example), the font I am given is BIGGER than point size 16 when created using Direct2D. (Using WinGDI it produces my reference size of 16 on the screen.) The Win32 function is my benchmark, and the directD version creates a bigger font than the Win32 code.

I have converted the point size input to this function as I think I need to, to provide DIP values to the Direct2D CreateTextFormat() function. Then I create a layout with a 0 length string to get the height for the default font created. This is then different to what I asked for to start with ...

I can't find any documentation that describes this in enough detail to get my head around this. Every site on the functions and structures just parrots the same stuff the windows website says about the structure contents. (Grrrr!!) Nowhere does it actually say if the text metric function output is in DIP or not, I'm assuming it is but can't see an obvious conversion from another format to get back to 16!! Please help :)

Thanks

Comment: why would you expect layout metrics to be equal to font size you're setting? Those too don't have to match, you don't specify font height in CreateTextFormat, but emsize. Regarding DWRITE_TEXT_METRICS, msdn explicitly says it's using DIPs.

Comment: sure, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368135(v=vs.85).aspx. I think most layout values are in DIPs, because specific DPI value is a runtime property.

Comment: Bunglehead, can you link to where on MSDN it say you should provide the emsize? From looking this definition up it itself has been an evolving definition from when it was first use for typography, and now different for digital fonts. In GDI you pass the Ascent + Descent value, aka the tmHeight from the metric of the font you want, and you get it. In directWrite they are asking for something else apparently but not telling people - IDWriteFactory::CreateTextFormat() spec page on MSDN just says to pass 'the logical size of the font' in DIP units, so I'm lost as to what this is exactly.

Comment: Sorry edited my comment. Thanks I will read.. So basically in my code I've asked for a 21.33 DIP size font (emHeight). But the GetMetrics function has a 'height' or size of 24.531 so I'm a bit lost lol

Comment: Yes, scaling that GDI does with ascent + descent height is not performed. So you shouldn't compare GDI font size to DirectWrite font size. Basically emsize is used for scaling design metrics that font provides. If you set emsize to DWRITE_FONT_METRICS.designUnitsPerEm you'll get font metrics in exactly design units.

Comment: I should've said previously; I have set the app up as DPI aware in the manifest file, so the scaling should not be done on any text automatically. I have checked this is not done as my monitor is scaled by 120% (1440p monitor) by default, and have changed it up and down to test. I am scaling all line and rectangle drawing operations myself based on DPI, and now am working on the text. I will look up the DWRITE_FONT_METRICS.designUnitsPerEm bit and see if I can get it working. Thanks

Comment: I don't think DPI awareness settings in manifest have any impact on DirectWrite behaviour, these are for higher level I believe. Like window system, UI controls, etc.